# Making use of getActivity() in a static method

Tags: java, android, static-methods

```
public class QRProductActivityPageObject {


    public static void testProductDetail() throws InterruptedException {

        ActivityTestRule<ProductInfoActivity> rule = new ActivityTestRule<ProductInfoActivity>(ProductInfoActivity.class, true, false);
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setClass(getActivity(), ProductInfoActivity.class);
        rule.launchActivity(intent);
        Thread.sleep(2000);
     }
}
```

The above syntax show error that you cant access getActivity() in static method .
But i want to call this new Activity(ProductInfoActivity) through static method only.Any suggestion??

Comment: add context into your function : ``testProductDetail(Context ctx)`` and use ``intent.setClass(ctx, ProductInfoActivity.class);``

Answer (score 0):

Pass context  when method call in Activity or fragment and get Activity from context in static method

```
 public static void testProductDetail(Context context) throws InterruptedException {

ActivityTestRule<ProductInfoActivity> rule = new  ActivityTestRule<ProductInfoActivity>(ProductInfoActivity.class, true, false);
Intent intent = new Intent();
Activity activity = (Activity) context;
intent.setClass(activity , ProductInfoActivity.class);
rule.launchActivity(intent);
Thread.sleep(2000);
 }
```

Call static method In activity

```
  testProductDetail(getApplicationContext());
```

In fragment

```
  testProductDetail(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
```

Answer (score 0):

Or use the solution I found around here a few weeks ago, it's pretty awesome and elegant. You'd be able to use it anywhere in your APP!

1. Create a class MyApplication (you could name it differently):

   ```
     public class MyApplication extends Application {
     private static Context context;

   public void onCreate() {
   super.onCreate();
   MyApplication.context = getApplicationContext();
   }

   public static Context getAppContext() {
   return MyApplication.context;
      }
   }
   ```
2. Go to your app Manifest file and add to the `<application...` tag the `android:name` attribute with the value of the name of the class we created:

   ```
   <application
   android:allowBackup="true"
   android:icon="@drawable/appico"
   android:label="@string/app_name"
   android:name="MyApplication"
   ```

Now you can get the context for your app from any class like that

> MyApplication.getAppContext();

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to call getActivity(). Instead of using setClass() method which requires you to give a context object, you can use [setClassName(String packageName, String className)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#setClassName(android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String)) method. Try this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setClassName("package.name.of.your.app", 
        ProductInfoActivity.class.getName());
```